# How to simplify a stretched exponential fit?

Tags: curve-fitting, interpolation

I have data from a Monte Carlo experiment that I was hoping to fit to a model of the form
$$\log(x y) \approx \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(z),$$
where I have many observations of triplets, $x, y, z$. This fit does a decent job, but when I look at the residuals of the fit versus $\log(z)$, there is a tell-tale bowl shape:
[image: residuals versus log(z), bowl shaped]

This suggests a fit of the form
$$\log(x y) \approx \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(z) + \beta_2 \left(\log(z)\right)^2,$$
I am not entirely opposed to such a fit, but my final goal is to state an equation that gives $x$ concisely in terms of $y$ and $z$. When I take the exponent of both sides of this fit, I get something really ugly:
$$x = \frac{c_0 z^{c_1 + c_2 \log(z)}}{y}$$
This was not what I was hoping for.

Is there some trick that I can use to get out of this mess? Ideally I would have one less constant, or at least not have a $z^{\log{z}}$ term.

**edit:** There is a strong theoretical reason to favor a fit of this form, instead of putting $\log y$ on the right hand side and performing a 'full' fit. If you do that, the coefficient associated with $\log y$ is nearly -1 anyway (-0.9989), but if you do, you do not see this 'quadratic' artifact with respect to the fitted values. It turns out that the $z=1$ case is a well known phenomenon for which $x = c / y$ is the commonly accepted law.

If it helps any, when I plot the residuals versus the more general model $$\log(x y) \approx \beta_0 + \beta_1 \log(z) + \beta_2 \left(\log(z)\right)^2,$$
I get this:
[image: residuals versus more general model]

Comment: I gather using $\log x=\alpha+\beta\log y+\gamma \log z$ was not apropriate? Just asking, since I would like to understand the logic behind using $\log xy$ as a response variable.

Comment: @mpiktas: perhaps there is theoretical or empirical evidence for a hyperbolic relationship between $x$ and $y$ when $z$ is fixed, i.e. $\beta=-1$.

Comment: @Henry, restrictions are testable anyway. It could be that without restriction there is no reason for square log. $c_1 = \beta_1$ and $c_2 = \beta_2$ no need for knew notations.

Comment: $xy$ is a discrete product? May be some more background could give more insights on how to proceed. Why log-log, why not S-curve or some other?

Comment: @mpiktas: as Henry guessed, there is a strong reason to favor $\beta = -1$. I put an edit in the question on this.

Comment: @Dmitrij Celov: I am not sure about the 'discrete product' part. I am intrigued by the 'S-curve' answer, of which I know nothing. My goal here was to produce a fit which a human can understand, with as few parameters as possible.

Comment: The edit even more clearly shows the need to transform $\log(xy)$: not only are the SDs of the residuals proportional to the square of the fit, they are strongly positively skewed.  If $x$ is supposed to depend on $y$, then consider re-expressing $x$ alone and including $y$ among the explanatory variables.  These plots strongly indicate something like $1/\log(x)$ or $\log(y)/\log(x)$ or $1/(\log(x)+log(y))$ or $\log(y) + 1/\log(x)$ are what you should be investigating.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do, if possible, is to take care of the heteroscedasticity.  Notice how the spread of the residuals consistently increases with the fit: in fact, the spread seems to increase almost quadratically with larger fit.

A standard cure is to return to the original response ($log(xy)$) and apply a strong transformation, such as a logarithm or even a reciprocal: something in that range is suggested by this pattern of heteroscedasticity.  Then redo the fitting and recheck the residuals.

It's a good idea to fit lines by eye, using graphs of transformed $xy$ against $z$ (or $\log(z)$.  This usually reveals more than any amount of manipulating a regression routine.  Once you have a suitable model, you can finally use least squares (or robust regression) to produce a final fit.

In this instance you might also want to explore the relationships among $x$ and $z$ and $y$ and $z$ separately to see whether just one of $x$, $y$ is causing the sudden change in slope between 2.9 and 3.6.  The change clearly is not quadratic: both "limbs" of the residual plot are linear.  One way to model this change--if it persists after you have dealt with the heteroscedasticity--is with a changepoint model that posits one value of the slope $\beta_1$ for, say, $z \le 3.2$, and a different value for $z \gt 3.2$.

Finally, in Monte-Carlo simulations you have full control and you know exactly the mechanism that produces the responses.  It can be useful to subject this to some analysis to find out just what the correct relationship among the triples ought to be.